# Cassandra:Only clustering key columns can be defined in CLUSTERING ORDER directive

Tags: cassandra

```
cqlsh> CREATE TABLE mykeyspace.counts (     company text,     day bigint,     type text,     host inet,     eventcount counter,    PRIMARY KEY ((company, day), type, host) ) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (company ASC, day ASC, ftype ASC, host ASC);

InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Only clustering key columns can be defined in CLUSTERING ORDER directive"
```

Why? How to fix?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have an ordering of `Partition Keys` because these keys declare how the Data is spread around the cluster and cannot be used for range queries. The partition keys are hashed before the data is placed on a node so unless you are using the ByteOrderedPartitioner (*do not use this*) the ordering is pretty much irrelevant as you need to do a full scan of all nodes to actually do a range query on those columns.

I would recommend looking through some basic data modeling talks to get more information on this:

[Data Modeling at Cassandra Day Chicago 2015](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jxGRbOpPql4)